# How to recover sql server after data drive crash (loss of master db mdf file)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

C drive is OS drive

D drive is data drive (system and user dbs)

E drive is log drive (system and user dbs)

D drive has crashed. So sql isn't starting as master mdf file is missing.

I could have started the sql server by pointing to the backup of master mdf file, then restore msdb/model/user dbs. But all my backup files are in .bak format.

I have full and log backups of system/user dbs (.bak). How do I extract the master mdf file to startup my sql server?

Maybe restore master on a new test server, then copy that master mdf file to the original sql server. Or would it be appropritae to rebuild system dbs, and then restore master/msdb/model/user dbs?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/rebuild-system-databases?view=sql-server-ver16#rebuild-system-databases-for-an-instance-of-sql-server then start SQL Server in Single User mode and restore `master.bak`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches I've worked with.

1. [Rebuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/rebuild-system-databases?view=sql-server-ver16) the system databases and then [restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-the-master-database-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16) `master` from a recent backup.
2. Get a copy of system databases from system/storage-level backup. If there are, say, volume snapshots of the disk containing system databases, those should be VSS consistent. Get a copy of the `master`'s files from there, and you should be good to go.

I recommend reading Gail Shaw's excellent article, [The SQL Server Instance That Will not Start](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/database-administration-sql-server/the-sql-server-instance-that-will-not-start/), for a repository of solutions for several kind of startup issues.